# Display alert message when user take screenshot in app

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do i display alert when user takes screenshot in iphone and  go out of the app until user delete it from iphone photo library.

Comment: And who thinks user wont use other device to capture screen even if u implement this sure to be rejected algo?

Comment: it just a programming overhead dnt try it user can mail image then del it then use ur app

Comment: yes.you are correct.but i need to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a screenshot via [Darwin notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html). As for detecting wether the screenshot was deleted, I don't think it is possible. Even if it was, it does not guarantee that the image was not uploaded or shared some other way.